# php relative img src detection

Tags: php, regex

i'm trying to build a php script that will capture all relative img src in an html code

i ended up in this little piece of code with pattern and replace function that seems to work in most cases:

```
        $base = "http://mycdn.example.org";
        $text = '<img src="/a.png" />';
        $text .= '<img src="//www.google.com/b.png" />';
        $text .='<img src="http://www.example.org/c.png" /<';
        $pattern = "/<img([^>]*) "."src=\"[^http|ftp|https]([^\"]*)\"/";
        $replace = "<img\${1} src=\"" . $base . "\${2}\"";
        $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
```

the results i except is that `a.png` will be replaced to the absolute url with the `$base` path but b and c shall remain untouched.

it works good for c but not for b where the protocol start as short for http, means,  start with 2 slashes (//)

```
`//www.google.com/b.png`
```

any help shall be greatly appriciated

Comment: Why don't you use a DOM parser?

Comment: how dom parser can help me find relative urls?

Comment: that don't seems to work

Comment: I would just add // to the ored protocols. i.e. `$pattern = "/<img([^>]*) "."src=\"[^http|ftp|https|\/\/]([^\"]*)\"/";` (untested code)

Comment: tried that either tensibai, didn't work